# React-Final-Form: Is there a way to not re-render form after component change?

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form, final-form

So, I'm having a hard time trying to figure this out.
Basically I have a component not related to React Final Form but inside the **Form** tags. The main approach is to when a user clicks on a button (in this case a tooth) its value changes and fills in with a purple color to show if its clicked - if not fills it with a white one. But when I fill in the Form and I click on the component that has the teeth the whole Form re-renders. Is there any way to handle this kind of behavior? Maybe I'm mistaken and it have something to do with my custom component.

Code got kinda big so i'll exemplify how it was built:

```
<Form
  initialValues={exam}
  onSubmit={onSubmit}
  render={({ handleSubmit, form, submitting, pristine, values }) => (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
     /*Custom component handling the teeth I mentioned*/
     <ConeBeam onClick={toothClicked} color="white" data={teeth} />
     /*TextField related to React-Final-Form using mui-rff*/
     <TextField
        label="Region"
        name="clark_region"
        size="small"
        fullWidth
     />
    </form>
  )}
/>

/*toothClicked function*/
function toothClicked({ id }) {

const tooth = parseInt(id);
const el = document.getElementById(id);

if (!teeth.includes(tooth)) {
  setTeeth([...teeth, tooth]);
  el.setAttribute("class", classes.primary);
} else {
  teeth.splice(teeth.indexOf(tooth), 1);
  setTeeth([...teeth]);
  el.setAttribute("class", classes.white);
}
```

}

**SOLVED!**
I was using useState which re-renders to change its state. Just changed setTeeth to a simple variable using let.

Comment: Show us `toothClicked` function?

Comment: Hi @ZohaibIjaz just updated the question body! My bad :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Form prop **initialValuesEqual**. For example: `initialValuesEqual={() => true}`

Comment: This is the only answer that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The form will rerender since that is how React works - if you change state or props for a component, the component will rerender. Consider moving the `ConeBeam` component into the parent if the rerender is an issue for your application.

Comment: I thought the same thing, will try it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to use `React.useCallabck()` for your callbacks especially `onSubmit` which is a prop to `Form` so on every parent re-render, your `onSubmit` get a new function reference which causes re-render of Form.

```js
const Parent = () => {
   const onSubmit = React.useCallback(() => {
       // do your submit logic here
   });
   return (
     <Form onSubmit={onSubmit} ... />
   );
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, the problem is that the whole render stuff is happening on the child component right before sending form values to parent (submitting).